# SQL Error 586 When running batch scripts through Flyway

Tags: sql-server, flyway

I am running some scripts through flyway migrate and I get this error in every script. The script itself runs but the next one doesn't.

```
The prepared statement handle 3 is not valid in this context.  
Please verify that current database, user default schema, and ANSI_NULLS and 
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER set options are not changed since the handle is prepared.
```

The Scripts ran fine last time but I havent executed them in a while. The other developer runs them fine on the laptop. I have checked the default settings for ANSI_Nulls and Quoted_Identifier on both laptops and they are same.

One thing to note is that all the scripts explicitly set ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to ON before executing and then turn Them off for example

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CalculateActionStatus]', N'FN') IS NULL
    EXEC('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateActionStatus] (@Dummy int) RETURNS int AS BEGIN RETURN 1 END;')
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateActionStatus]
       (@ActionID int)
   RETURNS int 
AS
BEGIN
       -- Action Status is basically the BIGGEST Status value of its child steps

       DECLARE @Status  int
       set @Status = 0

       select @Status = max(dbo.CalculateStepStatus(Start, Due, Completed, PercentComplete))
       from dbo.view_Step_ResolutionStep
       where ActionID = @ActionID

       RETURN isnull(@Status, 0)
END

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This could be a bug. Please file an issue in the issue tracker with exact steps how to reproduce, as well as the full stack trace and the SQL of a migration causing problems.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, but it was because I was using the JTDS driver. I changed to use the SQL server driver and it worked fine. This is actually noted in the Flyway [SQL Server Limitations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/sqlserver#limitations) documentation too.

JTDS connection string;

`flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myserver:1433/mydb`

SQL Server connection string;

`flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1433;databaseName=mydb`